# Cannot find form control in my dynamic form structure

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

After a few hours of research, I cannot resolve my error on my console:

`Error: Cannot find control with path: 'profileForm -> forms -> typeDePret' ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'profileForm -> forms -> amountDuLoan'`

However, it seems to me that I have structured my code correctly. I also cannot read the elements entered in the formcontrols.
I am attaching my typescript code:

```
    constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase, private fb: FormBuilder ) { 
    this.Formuser = fb.group({
      
     

      profileForm: fb.group({
        forms: this.fb.array([
          this.fb.group({
            typeDePret: ['' ],
            montantDuPret: [''],
            tauxDuPret: [''],
            dureeDuPret: [''],
            dureeDuPretMois: [''],
            dontDiffere: ['']
          })
        ])
      }),
      form: fb.group({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        dateDeNaissance: '',
        ville: '',
        tel: '',
        mail: '',
      })
    });

    }
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.profileForm = this.fb.group({
      forms: this.fb.array([this.createForm()])
    });
    
       
  }

  createForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      typeDePret: new FormControl(''),
      montantDuPret: new FormControl(''),
      tauxDuPret: new FormControl(''),
      dureeDuPret: new FormControl(''),
      dureeDuPretMois: new FormControl(''),
      dontDiffere: new FormControl('')
    });
  }

  get forms(): FormArray {
    return this.profileForm.get('forms') as FormArray;
  }
```

and here is my html:

```
<ng-template #effacer4>
  <div *ngIf="Next3; else effacer5" [@slideInOut]>
    <div formGroupName="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
      <div formArrayName="forms">
        <div *ngFor="let formControl of formControls; let i = index" [formControlName]="i" class="form">
          <p class='pretn'>Pret n° {{i+1}}</p>
          <label class="titredu">Type de prêt:</label><br>
          <select type="select" formControlName="typeDePret" class='form-select'>
            <option value="Prêt classique (amortissable)" class="select">Prêt classique (amortissable)</option>
            <option value="In fine" class="select">In fine</option>
            <option value="Prêt à taux Zéro" class="select">Prêt à taux Zéro</option>
            <option value="Prêt relais" class="select">Prêt relais</option>
          </select>

          <div class="group">
            <input type="text" formControlName="montantDuPret" id="montantDuPret" class="linput" required>
            <label for="montantDuPret" class="lelabel">Montant du prêt</label>
            <div class="bar"></div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a reproduction code on stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating form groups in a form array, so you need to reference form *group*, not form *control*.

So, you need to replace `[formControlName]="i"` with `[formGroupName]="i"`:

```
<div formArrayName="forms">
    <div *ngFor="let formControl of formControls; let i = index"  [formGroupName]="i" class="form">
        <p class='pretn'>Pret n° {{i+1}}</p>
```